# How to delete "SQL Server Agent" logs from "Log File Viewer"?

Tags: sql-server, delete, logs

On "SQL Server 2019" on Windows 2019:

1. I have opened Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
2. I logged into database server.
3. I clicked on "SQL Server Agent" and clicked on "Error logs" and double click on "Current".
4. Log File Viewer program is displayed. On right site I see plenty of errors, but that are old errors not important anymore. How to clear/delete those errors to remove clutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete individual entries, but you *can* tell SQL to start a fresh log.

To start a fresh log for the SQL Server Agent Error Log:

- exec msdb.dbo.[sp_cycle_agent_errorlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-agent-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16); or
- restart the SQL Server Agent service; or
- right-click at the "Error Logs" level in Object Explorer and choose `Recycle`

To start a fresh log for the SQL Server Error Log:

- exec master.dbo.[sp_cycle_errorlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16); or
- restart the SQL Server engine service

Comment: Executing `exec sp_cycle_agent_errorlog;`  and I have got error:
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_cycle_agent_errorlog'.

Now I see I can right click on "Error Logs" folder and select "Recycle". If looking at T-SQL it is: `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_cycle_agent_errorlog`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.